# I need help deciphering what this palindrome function is doing

Tags: python

I am teaching myself Python through YouTube, and have no idea how this works.
Can someone explain me how this works?

```
def palin(x):
    palin = input("word; ")
    x = len(palin)
    y = x - 1
    i = 0
    while i < y:
        if palin[i] == palin[y]:
            i = i + 1
            y = y - 1
            print("is palindrome")
            print(True)
            break
        else:
            print("Is not palindrome")
            print(False)
            break
    return None
```

Comment: If that code is typical of your YouTube tutor, I urge you to please find someone else to learn from.

Comment: "explain how this works" — it **doesn't** work. It only checks the first and last letter of the input string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this horrible code at least work, you need remove some interfering or useless lines, and moving one line to the end:

```
def palin(x):
    palin = input("word: ")
    x = len(palin)
    y = x - 1
    i = 0
    while i < y:
        if palin[i] == palin[y]:
            i = i + 1
            y = y - 1
        else:
            print("Is not palindrome")
            return
    print("is palindrome")
```

Initially, `i` is the index (position) of the first letter, `y` is the index of the last letter. Symbols at those positions are in the `while` loop checked repeatedly for equality, and after each successful check `i` is increased and `y` is decreased, so the next pair of the "opposite" symbols will be checked:

```
        +---+---+---+---+---+
        | r | a | d | a | r |
        +---+---+---+---+---+
          ↑               ↑
          i               y        ←----------- Initial positions
              ↑       ↑
              i       y            ←----------- Next positions
```

If all tests for equality pass (as in my picture), the `else` branch is never introduced, so the text string `"is palindrome"` is printed.
In the opposite case, the `else` branch takes the action, prints the string `"Is not palindrome"` and the `return` statement immediately finishes your `palin()` function.